# Verdaccio crash with Error [ERR_STREAM_DESTROYED]: Cannot call write after a stream was destroyed

Tags: javascript, node.js, verdaccio

We are hosting a Verdaccio 3.4.0 npm private registry within docker.

It use a mounted volume to store packages.

For some reason, the container started to crash, it can now start but it can't see any packages:

[image]

I have checked and the mounted volumes is still: `/verdaccio/storage`

I noticed that the disk space was full, but even after cleaning more than half of the full disk space, it keep saying there's no packages published.

This is becoming critical since it impacts all our CI,

How can I restore the state of my server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to spread knowledge, we have a chat (verdaccio community [chat](http://chat.verdaccio.org)) about this issue. Your reasons were:

- Lack of hard-drive space was not allowing Verdaccio to create or modify files.
- Your database was corrupted (empty) due the first point, as reminder, Verdaccio open files and try to write to the, specially database when you publish new packages

Solution was simple, clear some space in your disk, restart the server and restore from backup a previous `.sinopia-db.json` database.

Keep always backups :-)

Comment: This happened to me once more, again disk space full. It would be nice to prevent this file from being corrupted. Also, I have found that last time when I fixed it, in march, I used a different volume which was as no backup. Is there a way to regenerate that file?

Comment: Not yet, I recommend regular backups of that file.

Comment: I restored the 3month old backup file. Do you see any issue with it? My jwt seems to be working. What happen if a package I am securing is not in the list anymore ?